# resizeMode="contain" makes my images blinking on changin route or updating state in React-Native app

Tags: react-native

I'm using resizeMode="contain" for my images and when I change view or update state they keep blinking on android devices.
if I change to stretch it works but I need to use contain.
How can I fix this issue?

here is my code:

```
_constructHearts = (heartCount) => {
    let hearts = [];    
    for (let i = 1; i <=heartCount; i++) {
      hearts.push(
        <Image 
          source={icons['heartIcon']} 
          style={{height: normalize(22),width: normalize(22)}}
          resizeMode="contain"
          resizeMethod="auto"
          key={makeid(4)}
        />        
      );
    }
    if(5 - heartCount > 0){
       let noHeart = 5 - heartCount;
       for (let i = 1; i <=noHeart; i++) {
        hearts.push(
          <Image 
            source={icons['heartIconDis']} 
            style={{height: normalize(22), width: normalize(22)}}
            resizeMode="contain"
            resizeMethod="auto"
            key={makeid(4)}
          /> 
        );
      }
    }        
    return hearts;
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think the function is re-executed when rendering is re-enabled. Control reuse.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I control this? I have state update based on some functionality in my view, and on every state update it starts blinking.